# Is there a relation between the p-values of coefficients and the $R^2$ in an OLS regression?

Tags: regression, p-value, least-squares, regression-coefficients, r-squared

I have a very simple question. I know that the R-squared is the proportion of the variance for a dependent variable that's explained by an independent variable or variables in a regression model.

I also know that the p-value is the probability of obtaining test results at least as extreme as the results actually observed, under the assumption that the null hypothesis is correct.

My question essentially is, is the value of the R-squared only dependent on the coefficients? Or also on the significance of the coefficients? In other words, does an increase in the p-value of a Beta estimate, *ceteris paribus* (everything else equal) affect the R-squared?

Comment: "Does an increase in the p-value of a Beta estimate, ceteris paribus (everything else equal) affect the R-squared?" this seems me a bad posed question. If "everything else equal" is not clear why p-value increase.

Comment: @markowitz Please feel free to suggest a better posed question..

Comment: From your reply It seems me that a better title would be: “usual vs robust standard error, affect also $R^2$ value in regression estimated with OLS?”. As you noted the reply is no.

Comment: @markowitz Well, that was not really the point of the question though. I wanted to know if the p-value was somehow connected the R2. My answer, was simply a way I thought I could check it with. Your are suggesting that I base my question on the answer. That would not really help anyone who has the same question as I have right?

Comment: If it is so, my initial doubt come back. P-value is an output of estimate not an input. You have to declare what we can move and what not in the comparison. Otherwise you can ask "explain relations between p-value of coefficients and $R^2$ in OLS regression"

Comment: Changed the title to your suggestion. My question was merely posed as a thought experiment. I thought that it would make clearer what I was looking for and reduce the risk of getting comments that were beside the point. Going on our discussion I was wrong ;)

Comment: Well, now I do not have time. Probably later I propose my answer.

Comment: I added my answer

Comment: This question is (very) ambiguous.  Please tell us which "coefficients" you mean: the *model* values or the *estimated* values?  Where you ask about an "increase in the p-value of a beta estimate," exactly what do you propose to change in order to effect that increase? Are you contemplating holding the explanatory variable values fixed or do you seek a general result, regardless of what those values might be?  What exactly is "everything else" in your supposition: the model coefficients only? Or the data only? Or both? Or some combination of subsets?

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a relation between the p-values of coefficients and the R2 in
> an OLS regression?

In *variables selection* context if we add one regressor the $R^2$ increase, or at worst remain the same. So if you add and add regressors, $R^2$ approach to 1.

Moreover, is less known that if the regressor added have a p-value less than $0,32$ (about) also the $R_{adj}^2$ increase. So, this indicator tell us that more significative the regressors are more the $R^2$ increase.

Related: [Should $ R^2$ be calculated on training data or test data?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/348330/should-r2-be-calculated-on-training-data-or-test-data/496514#496514;) [How to calculate out of sample R squared?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/228540/how-to-calculate-out-of-sample-r-squared/492581#492581)

Answer (score 2):

The F-statistic on which the computation of a p-value is based can be expressed in terms of $R^2$ (and also the degrees of freedom).

See also [Does $r$-squared have a $p$-value?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/111602/does-r-squared-have-a-p-value)

The relationship between $R^2$ and the F-statistic is for [simple linear regression](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_linear_regression) with a sample of size $n$ the following

$$F = \frac{R^2}{1-R^2} (n-2)$$

So yes, there is a relation between p-value and $R^2$.

In the case of OLS regression other than simple linear regression, then the relationship will be more complex and the F statistic is expressed in terms of the *two* $R^2$ values of the model with and without the parameter included

---

#### Example

Below is a demonstration by simulating uncorrelated data (sample size $n=10$ with data from normal distribution) and computing the p-value for the slope coefficient as well as the $R^2$ value. In the figure we see that the two are related.

[image: example]

```
sim = function(n = 10) {
   # simulate uncorrelated data
   x = rnorm(n)
   y = rnorm(n)
   
   # compute r^2 and p-value
   mod = lm(y~x)
   r2 = summary(mod)$r.squared
   p = summary(mod)$coefficients[,4][2]

   return(list(r2=r2,p=p))
}

set.seed(1)

plot(-100,-100, xlim = c(0,1), ylim = c(0,1),
     xlab = "p-value", ylab = "R squared")

for (i in 1:1000) {
    s = sim()
    points(s$p,s$r2,
           pch = 21, col = 1, bg = 1, cex = 0.7)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I realised shortly after posting, that my question can be quite easily answered by running a regression with and without robust standard errors.

I found a Stata example that does just that here: https://www.statology.org/robust-standard-errors-stata/

The R-squared stays the same, so the p-value (affected by robust standard errors) does not change the R-squared.

Comment: If you've changed from OLS to robust standard errors, you're no longer using the same model, so it's certainly not the case that *all else is equal*.

Comment: Well, the estimates do not change, the R squared does not change. Could you explain then it what ways it matters?

Answer (score 0):

The $R^2$ is a function of the explained error and the total error. The $p$-value for a coefficiant is a function of the $t$ statistic for that coefficient which includes the standard error in the denominator. The standard error of a coefficient is also function of the explained error among other inputs. As the values both partially depend on the same inputs, it's fair to say there is a relationship. [This PDF](https://www3.nd.edu/%7Erwilliam/stats1/x91.pdf) gives a more explicit functional form for the relationship between a coefficient's standard error and the $R^2$.