# What is the formula for the p value of a tendline?

Tags: regression, p-value, linear, trend

I can't find any no matter how hard I google. Every search result just tells me either how to calculate it on excel or explains what the p value is.

Comment: Are you able to obtain the estimate for the trend line and the standard error by yourself?

Comment: Yes, I know how to find r^2, the slope and intercept, the standard error, as well as the standard deviation for both the input and output.

Comment: Can you also find the associated test statistic and degrees of freedom for that test statistic?

Comment: It's a Student test or, equivalently, an F test, as explained at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/111616/919.  Googling [p value regression slope](https://www.google.com/search?q=compute+p-value+regression+slope) turns up pages of instructions: take your pick.